# Java slow down for loop without slowing down rest of program

Tags: java, for-loop, slowdown

I'm creating a video game and I've got a for loop that recovers your health

```
public void recoverHealth() {
    if (curHealth < finalHealth) {
        for (double i = 0; i < finalHealth; i = i + 0.1) {
            curHealth = curHealth + 0.1;
            System.out.println("health: " + curHealth);
        }
    }
}
```

But the problem is that java goes through this so fast it goes from 0-20 before the game even starts. How can I possibly slow down the recoverHealth() method without slowing down the entire game such as Thread.sleep doesn't work..

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Run the health regeneration method on it's own separate thread in which you call Thread.sleep

Comment: How you do this depends *heavily* on how the rest of your game is implemented, and it's not really possible for us to give you a good answer here. You could create a separate thread (and implement proper synchronization), you could run your application at a fixed, controlled frame rate and increment health once per frame, you could start a separate timer that periodically increments health, etc.

Comment: Also, by the way, the problem you are having isn't that Java is doing it too fast; it's that you're doing it in a for loop that doesn't terminate until all the health has been added. By the time your loop exits, all health will be recovered no matter *how* fast you do it in the loop, so if you call that function as soon as your program starts, it will execute that loop before moving on to do the next thing. Hence suggestions for threads, per-frame updates, timers, etc.

Comment: Make you recoverHealth() a `TimerTask` contrary to popular belief TimerTasks are very useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put `recoverHealth` into a separate thread, and use `Thread.sleep()` as you describe.

Answer (score 3):

Add this to your game program, where curHealth is accessible.

```
timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask (){
    public void run() {
        curHealth = curHealth + 0.1;
    }
}, 1000);
```